# Importing a JSON using MongoDB and mLab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to import a JSON to my sandbox cluster on mLab using the following steps:

1. I run mongod.
2. Open new tab and run the following command pointing to my mlab cluster:

---

```
mongoimport -h ds127341.mlab.com:27341 -d <<<mydatabasename>>> -c <<<collection>>> -u <<<username>>> -p <<<password>>> --file <<<mypath>>>
```

---

However, I get this error:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
```

After reading some more, I also added the options `--ssl` and `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates`, and I get the following error:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers, openssl error: read tcp 192.168.1.69:51933->54.225.0.238:27341: read: connection reset by peer
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to import my json to my mlab cluster given these strange errors?
[image]

Comment: There is a flag in the MongoDB docs `--authenticationDatabase admin` which may help - https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/import/#import-the-sample-data-into-the-inventory-collection. Unfortunately I'm experiencing a different issue (`mongoimport is undefined`) so can't verify if this helps.